# Check if the given Matrix has Valid dimensions - JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, 2d

I want to check if the given **Matrix** has valid dimensions.
This Matrix Below has **Invalid Dim** because it does not satisfy Matrix properties

```
Matrix x = new Matrix(new double[][]{
                { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0},
                { 4.0, 5.0 }
        })
```

I have tried a couple of Methods the latest was:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                if (array[i][j] = null) {
                    throw new InvalidDimensionsException("Invalid Dim");
                }
            }
        }
```

It's just that it's not **null**, it just has no element there!
Unfortunately, nothing worked and I ran out of Idea.

I will be glad to hear your suggestions

Thanks in advance

Comment: the Invalid part is:
                { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0},
                { 4.0, 5.0,x }
where x is should have an element otherwise it's Invalid Matrix Dim
All rows and cols must contain an element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cells of a `double[][]` cannot be null, so the code in the question is meaningless, especially since it doesn't compile (`=` should be `==`).

To verify that the 2D array is a rectangle, i.e. a valid matrix, do it like this:

```java
double[][] matrix = {
        { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0},
        { 4.0, 5.0 }
};
```

```java
int height = matrix.length;
if (height == 0)
    throw new InvalidDimensionsException("Invalid Dim");
int width = matrix[0].length;
if (width == 0)
    throw new InvalidDimensionsException("Invalid Dim");
for (int y = 1; y < height; y++)
    if (matrix[y].length != width)
        throw new InvalidDimensionsException("Invalid Dim");
```

The code will throw `NullPointerException` is any of the arrays are `null`.

Comment: This code works, but empty matrices are valid. You can have matrices that are 0x0, 10x0, 0x5, etc

Comment: @user That's for OP to decide whether an [empty matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Empty_matrices) is considered valid, and adjust the code shown here accordingly. Height of zero has to be tested to prevent exception, but OP can choose a different action to take, if needed.

Comment: All right. I assumed the OP would be using the math definition, but I guess their specific use case could be different

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of columns the matrix must have, you can check the size of each 1-D array inside.

```
double[][] mat = ...; //get the underlying array from the matrix
for (double[] arr : mat) if (arr.length != numCols) throw new InvalidDimensionsException(...);
```

Otherwise, you can take the size of the first row and check if all rows have the same length.

```
//If it's empty, there's no point checking further
if (mat.length != 0) {
  //All the rows should have this same length
  int numCols = mat[0].length;
  for (int i = 1; i < mat.length; i ++)
    if (mat[i].length != numCols) throw new InvalidDimensionsException(...);
}
```